# Prototype cells not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview

My tableView has two prototype cells which are programmed in the storyboard as below.[image: The two cells in question]

The identifiers are all correct another isn't a mistake between the IB and the storyboard as the identifiers link up. But when I build and run the project I get presented with the following screen (Note that on this run, semester.subjects and semester.activities are empty).[image: Running my project]

Also notice that when I click my first cell, nothing happens but when I click my second cell it changes to what I wanted it to be. My question is How does this happen? Also below is my cellForRowAt indexPath if you need it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subjectCell", for: indexPath) as! SubjectTableViewCell
    let addCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addCell", for: indexPath) as! AddSubjectTableViewCell
    var cellToAdd = UITableViewCell()
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if indexPath.row < semester.subjects.count{
        let subject = semester.subjects[indexPath.row]
            cell.subjectColourView.backgroundColor = subject.colour
            cell.subjectLabel.text = subject.name
            cell.teacherLabel.text = subject.teacher
        cellToAdd = cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == semester.subjects.count {
            cellToAdd = addCell
        }
    case 1:
        if indexPath.row < semester.activities.count{
        let activity = semester.activities[indexPath.row]
            cell.subjectColourView.backgroundColor = activity.colour
            cell.subjectLabel.text = activity.name
            cell.teacherLabel.text = activity.teacher
        cellToAdd = cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == semester.activities.count {
            cellToAdd = addCell
        }

    default:
        break
    }
    print(cellToAdd.reuseIdentifier)
    return cellToAdd


}
```

Here is the entire TVC

```
import UIKit
```

class SubjectTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var semester: Semester!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return semester.subjects.count + 1
    case 1:
        return semester.activities.count + 1
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return "Subjects"
    case 1:
        return "Extracurricular Activities"
    default:
        return nil
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subjectCell", for: indexPath) as! SubjectTableViewCell
    let addCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addCell", for: indexPath) as! AddSubjectTableViewCell
    var cellToAdd = UITableViewCell()
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if indexPath.row < semester.subjects.count{
        let subject = semester.subjects[indexPath.row]
            cell.subjectColourView.backgroundColor = subject.colour
            cell.subjectLabel.text = subject.name
            cell.teacherLabel.text = subject.teacher
        cellToAdd = cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == semester.subjects.count {
            cellToAdd = addCell
        }
    case 1:
        if indexPath.row < semester.activities.count{
        let activity = semester.activities[indexPath.row]
            cell.subjectColourView.backgroundColor = activity.colour
            cell.subjectLabel.text = activity.name
            cell.teacherLabel.text = activity.teacher
        cellToAdd = cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == semester.activities.count {
            cellToAdd = addCell
        }

    default:
        break
    }
    print(cellToAdd.reuseIdentifier)
    return cellToAdd


}
}
```

Comment: Please add more of your code in your question, we can easy test your code, you just add a part of your code.

Comment: @aircraft What do you want?

Comment: Please add you `didSelecteCellAtIndexPath` code. Also, please describe the behavior that you want, as it's not entirely obvious what the desired outcome is.

Comment: @needshelp post more as more of your useful code , so we easy to copy it to our test project, to find where the issue is.

Comment: @aircraft I added the entire TVC. Don't think it will help much. The desired outcome is for two 'add another' rows

Comment: @aircraft No, it isn't convenient.

Comment: @needshelp Will you share  your project with me, if you dont mind ? I will see your problem and give solution that you expected

Answer (score 0):

The problem, for who knows what reason, is that the cell was denied outside of the switch.

```
 if indexPath.row < semester.subjects.count{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subjectCell", for: indexPath) as! SubjectTableViewCell
    let subject = semester.subjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.subjectColourView.backgroundColor = subject.colour
        cell.subjectLabel.text = subject.name
        cell.teacherLabel.text = subject.teacher
    cellToAdd = cell
    }
```